# mysql update a table with counts of another table

Tags: mysql-error-1054

if you could help I would be very thankful.
there are two tables,  customers and lead_report

I want to take the counts from the first column and place them in the matching row of the second column.

select leadsource,count(*)  from customers where leadsource is not null and leadsource !="" group by leadsource;

```
select leadsource,count(*)  from customers where leadsource is not null  and leadsource !="" group by leadsource;

+---------------------+----------+
| leadsource          | count(*) |
+---------------------+----------+
| Show 2014           |        2 |
| Show 2013           |        4 |
| By Me               |        1 |
+---------------------+----------+


select source,leads from lead_report;

+---------------------+-------+    
| source              | leads |
+---------------------+-------+
| Show 2014           |     0 |
| Show 2013           |     0 |
| By Me               |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+



update lead_report leads inner join 
(select leadsource,count(*)  from customers where leadsource is not null    and leadsource !="" group by leadsource)
customers using (leadsource) set lead_report.leads =  customers.leadsource;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'leadsource' in 'from clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update lead_report lr join 
(select leadsource, count(*) cnt from customers 
where leadsource is not null  and leadsource !="" group by leadsource) cust
ON lr.source=cust.leadsource
SET lr.leads=cust.cnt;
```

Comment: update lead_report lr join  (select leadsource, count(*) cnt from customers  where leadsource is not null  and leadsource !="" group by leadsource) cust ON lr.source=cust.leadsource SET lr.leads=cust.cnt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0